# Custom WordPress block not loading into editor using block.json, register_block_type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WordPress theme that I'm trying to add a custom block through. I was [following this tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/), but for a theme instead of a plugin.

I have a directory /src/blocks/jcal-testimonial with a file block.json:

```
{
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "title": "JCal testimonial",
    "name": "jcal/testimonial",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js"
}
```

And index.js:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

// Register the block
registerBlockType('jcal/testimonial', {
    title: "JCal testimonial",
    edit: function () {
        return <p> Hello world (from the editor)</p>;
    },
    save: function () {
        return <p> Hola mundo (from the frontend) </p>;
    },
});
```

and I use wp-scripts to build it into a corresponding index.js, index.asset.php and block.json in build/blocks/jcal-testimonial.

In functions.php, I have the following code to register the block:

```
function add_testimonial_block() {
    register_block_type(get_template_directory_uri() . "build/blocks/jcal-testimonial");
}

add_action("init", "add_testimonial_block");
```

But the block doesn't show up in the editor. In the browser devtools, the JS file is never loaded. There are no console or PHP errors. Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: ok I've come up with a workaround by not using block registration at all and j `wp_enqueue_script( "jcal-testimonial-js", get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/blocks/jcal-testimonial/index.js", array("wp-blocks", "wp-element", "wp-block-editor", "wp-components"));` in `add_testimonial_block`. works but seems p jank

Comment: also changed name from `jcal-testimonial` to `jcal/testimonial` bc it requires a namespace, and added a `title` field to the registerBlockType object argument